# Any good emulator is able to emulate Trust Zone?

Tags: android, emulator

I am trying to setup a development environment to use Trustzone on an Android Emulator.

It seems Linaro and QEMU are only provide ARM emulating. Any other emulator provide good support of the Trustzone?

Thanks,

Rong

Comment: Sorry, questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic here. You might try [softwarerecs.se] after going through their help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic in the oper source community, there is two main things to emulate Trusted Execution Environment (TEE), they are Open-TEE and OPTEE.

Trust Zone is the ARM security tech about TEE, Intel, on the other hand, has Intel Trust Execution Technology (TXT). AMD comes with SKINIT (AMD-V).

Open-TEE is the environment I am going to use.